# Number of objects created

Tags: objective-c, c, class, object

I've created functions that created objects but i can't figure out how to make sure that every objects perform that function

```
-(id) init{
   if (self = [super init]){
       _die = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}

-(void) addDice:(Die *)d{
    [_die addObject:d];
}

-(void) roll{
    for (int i=0; i<_die; i++) //this is the part i don't get how to do'
    {
        Die *d = _die[i];
        [d roll];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NSMutableArray` instance has a method `-count` to get the number of objects currently in the array. You may want to do this:

```
-(void)roll{
    for (int i=0; i<_die.count; i++) //Enumerate the array
    {
        Die *d = [_die objectAtIndex:i]; // Get the i th object in _die.
        [d roll];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can also you the enumerator or fast enumeration: `for(Die *d in _die) {...}`